# Sorteio onde o nome não pode ser sorteado mais de uma vez

Tags: c#, .net, random

Preciso fazer um software simples de sorteio, mas não sei como pegar os nomes que foram inseridos no list box e sortear um entre eles. O mesmo nome não pode ser sorteado mais que uma vez. Como fazer essa parte?

Comment: Você está usando um ListBox mesmo? Não vai usar um ListView?

Comment: Tem um fator que parece que você deseja, tipo (exemplo) aperte o botão e busca o nome, ai aperta o botão novamente busca qualquer nome diferente do primeiro nome e ai sucessivamente?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 13):

### Implementação do algoritmo de embaralhamento Fisher-Yates:

Uma saída simples para o seu caso seria produzir uma cópia embaralhada da lista de nomes, para que você possa ir retirando os mesmos um a um.

Isto dá para fazer com uma função bem curta e eficiente:

```
   static Random _random = new Random();
   public static void Shuffle<T>(T[] array)
   {
      var random = _random;
      for (int i = array.Length; i > 1; i--)
      {
         int j = random.Next(i);
         T tmp = array[j];
         array[j] = array[i - 1];
         array[i - 1] = tmp;
      }
   }
```

**Características:**

- É de ordem O(n).
- Caso você precise sortear toda a lista, acaba sendo mais eficiente do que sortear ítens individuais um por um e controlando o que já foi sorteadi,
- Esta função é facilmente adaptável a outras coleções, além de arrays.

### Código completo para teste:

```
using System;
public class Sorteio
{
   // Esta é a função de embaralhamento que você deve implementar no seu código:
   static Random _random = new Random();

   public static void Shuffle<T>(T[] array)
   {
      var random = _random;
      for (int i = array.Length; i > 1; i--)
      {
         int j = random.Next(i);
         T tmp = array[j];
         array[j] = array[i - 1];
         array[i - 1] = tmp;
      }
   }
   // Teste do algoritmo:
   public static void Main()
   {
      // Aqui você deve pegar os valores da sua lista:
      string[] array = { "Alaor", "Joseval", "Salustiano", "Gomide", "Castro" };
      // Embaralhamos a lista...
      Shuffle(array);
      // ... e, uma vez embaralhada a lista, não precisa sortear novamente.
      // basta ir pegando os resultados um por um, que os nomes não se repetirão:
      foreach (string value in array)
      {
         Console.WriteLine(value);
      }      
   }
}
```

> Veja o resultado no IDEONE: http://ideone.com/aki905

<sub>Implementação adaptada de http://www.dotnetperls.com/fisher-yates-shuffle</sub>

Answer (score 8):

Tenho uma alternativa a implementação do Bacco com algumas vantagens:

- Permite o uso de **qualquer lista**, inclusive um *array* que é uma lista. Pode ser mais adequado para a sua utilização específica.
- A geração do aleatório usa uma semente diferente da padrão.
- Permite **embaralhamento parcial** dos elementos da lista (se certamente **nunca** for necessário pode ser facilmente retirado para diminuir o tamanho do código).
- O método permite uma **sintaxe mais regular** e facilitando o *Intellisense* (é como o `Shuffle` fizesse parte de qualquer lista declarada).

Talvez você precise de algo que seja apenas o meio termo entre uma solução e outra. Pode não precisar

Você não falou nada se a lista pode ser alterada *in-place*. Se não puder, precisa de um [algoritmo modificado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/18801/101).

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class Sorteio {
    public static void Main() {
        var lista = new List<string>() { "Alaor", "Joseval", "Salustiano", "Gomide", "Castro" };
        lista.Shuffle();
        foreach (var valor in lista) {
            WriteLine(valor);
        }
        WriteLine("//////////");
        string[] array = { "Alaor", "Joseval", "Salustiano", "Gomide", "Castro" };
        array.Shuffle(2);
        foreach (var valor in array) {
            WriteLine(valor);
        }
        WriteLine("//////////");
        int[] array2 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        array2.Shuffle(1,4);
        foreach (var valor in array2) {
            WriteLine(valor);
        }
    }
}

namespace System.Collections.Generic {
    public static class IListExt {
        static Random r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

        public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list, int lowerItem, int upperItem) {
            upperItem = upperItem > list.Count ? list.Count : upperItem;
            lowerItem = lowerItem < 0 ? 0 : lowerItem;
            for (int i = lowerItem; i < upperItem; i++) {
                int j = r.Next(i, upperItem);
                T tmp = list[j];
                list[j] = list[i];
                list[i] = tmp;
            }
        }

        public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list, int upperItem) {
            list.Shuffle(0, upperItem);
        }

        public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list) {
            list.Shuffle(0, list.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/VcSOSj). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cIcgFW). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/FisherYates.cs).

Para abandonar a faixa opcional de embaralhamento, basta eliminar os *overloads*, retirar os parâmetros adicionais no método principal, as linhas de normalização destes parâmetros e usar o valor *default* diretamente.

Se precisar de uma segurança maior na geração dos números aleatórios. Tem a opção de usar `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` mas já complica um pouco mais.

Answer (score 8):

Resolvi colocar outra resposta já que alguém pode precisar de um embaralhamento sem alterar a enumeração original.

Aproveitei para melhorar, depois de fazer alguns testes, e vi que qualquer enumeração pode ser usada neste caso.

Retirei a faixa de itens que serão embaralhados que tem utilidade restrita. Porém adicionei um exemplo para pegar uma quantidade menor de resultados após o embaralhamento. Claro que poderia ter sido usado um `for` simples ou pegar elementos individuais manualmente. Neste caso teria que manipular o enumerador da estrutura [`IEnumerable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?view=netcore-3.1&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) gerada.

Pode parecer um algoritmo pior e de fato é um pouco mais lento que o algoritmo que altera a coleção de dados diretamente, mas este novo algoritmo continua tendo complexidade O(n).

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class Sorteio {
    public static void Main() {
        var lista = new List<string>() { "Alaor", "Joseval", "Salustiano", "Gomide", "Castro" };
        foreach (string value in lista.Shuffle()) {
            WriteLine(value);
        }
        WriteLine("////////");
        foreach (string value in lista.Shuffle().Take(3)) {
            WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}

namespace System.Collections.Generic {
    public static class IEnumerableExt {
        static Random r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        
        public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list) {
            T[] array = list.ToArray();
            for (int i = array.Length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                int j = r.Next(i + 1);
                T tmp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[i];
                array[i] = tmp;
            }
            foreach(var item in array) {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/6bz7lM). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HtRy7L). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/FisherYates2.cs).

Answer (score 4):

Eu vim transcrever um algoritmo mais sofisticado para resolver este problema.
Esse algoritmo tem pelo menos duas vantagens sobre o Fisher-Yates:

- Não muda a lista original (evita uma cópia caso preservar a lista original seja necessário)
- Faz menos acessos a memória (isto pode implicar melhor performance, mas não usei nenhuma ferramenta para medir a performance por isso não estou apto para fazer comparações)

Desvantagem

- Não muda a lista original (se for necessário percorrer os elementos mais que uma vez pode ser benéfico usar Fisher-Yates)
- É mais complicado implementar

[Esta é uma implementação do algoritmo descrito neste blog](http://blog.demofox.org/2013/07/06/fast-lightweight-random-shuffle-functionality-fixed/).

```
public static class Shuffler
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> Shuffle(this IList<int> items, int seed = 0)
    {
        int count = items.Count();
        int pow4 = 4;
        while (count > pow4)
        {
            pow4 *= 4;
        }

        int numBits = 0;
        int mask = pow4 - 1;
        while (mask != 0)
        {
            mask = mask >> 1;
            numBits++;
        }

        // calculate our left and right masks to split our indices for the feistel 
        // network
        int halfNumBits = numBits / 2;
        int rightMask = (1 << halfNumBits) - 1;
        int leftMask = rightMask << halfNumBits;

        for (int i = 0; i < pow4; ++i)
        {
            int shuffleIndex = EncryptIndex(i, halfNumBits, leftMask, rightMask, seed);

            // if we found a valid index, return success!
            if (shuffleIndex < count)
            {
                yield return items[shuffleIndex];
            }
        }
    }

    private static int MurmurHash2(int key, int seed)
    {
        // 'm' and 'r' are mixing constants generated offline.
        // They're not really 'magic', they just happen to work well.
        const int m = 0x5bd1e995;
        const int r = 24;

        // Initialize the hash to a 'random' value

        int h = seed ^ 4;

        // Mix 4 bytes at a time into the hash
        int k = key;

        k *= m; 
        k ^= k >> r; 
        k *= m; 

        h *= m; 
        h ^= k;

        // Do a few final mixes of the hash to ensure the last few
        // bytes are well-incorporated.

        h ^= h >> 13;
        h *= m;
        h ^= h >> 15;

        return h;
    }

    private static int EncryptIndex(int index, int halfNumBits, int leftMask, int rightMask, int seed)
    {

        int left = (index & leftMask) >> halfNumBits;
        int right = (index & rightMask);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {
            int newLeft = right;
            int newRight = left ^ (MurmurHash2(right, seed) & rightMask);
            left = newLeft;
            right = newRight;
        }

        // put the left and right back together to form the encrypted index
        return (left << halfNumBits) | right;
    }

}
```

Nota: Chame o Shuffle com uma `seed` diferente, ou altere a implementação para usar um valor variável tal como `Environment.TickCount`

Comment: Acho que ficou bem melhor mesmo. Devidamente upada. Ja limpei os meu comments de cima, e jaja apago esse.