# Embaralhar números de uma lista?

Tags: c#, .net, lista, random

Bom, inicialmente, não entendo muito de lista em C#, mas tenho uma lista do tipo `int` que sempre vai ter 4 elementos que são: `1, 2, 3 e 4`, estou atribuindo eles com o `.Add`, se alguém souber outro jeito me dê um help..

Eu queria embaralhar os itens dessa lista sempre, ou seja, ter uma função para embaralhar os itens da lista e me retornar a lista embaralhada para eu poder usar ela.

> Exemplo:
>
> Uma lista: 1, 2, 3, 4
>
> Retornar: 2, 1, 4 ,3 (aleatoriamente)

E depois disso, eu tenho que usar os elementos dessa lista, como faço isso?  Na lista do exemplo a embaralhada ficou `2, 1, 4, 3` como uso cada valor desse no código como uma variável inteiro? Exemplo: Quero atribuir á uma variável `soma` o valor do 1º e 3º elemento da lista embaralhada, como indico o 1º e 3º elemento para a `soma`?

Comment: Foi uma duplicata pois a anterior não era duplicata na minha opinião, até que a resposta mais simples não foi a mesma, então pra mim não é duplicata, eram situações diferentes.

Comment: É duplicata da que você perguntou que é duplicata da outra porque dá a mesma resposta. Quando as respostas de uma pergunta já feita não te satisfazem você coloca uma recompensa. Mas lá não te satisfez porque se produz exatamente o resultado que você espera? A mais simples também resolve de um jeito que você que está começando não tem ideia do que seja esse monte de coisa, ñ está pronta para uso em qualquer código. Se quisesse algo mais simples você teria dito que leu lá e queria algo "mais simples" (embora mais simples é um conceito subjetivo),aí as pessoas saberiam o que você está procurando.

Comment: Nada haver, para muitos i termo embaralhar pode ser definido em outras palavras como trocar, alterar etc e nem por busca no site tu encontra, só acho que deveria comentar com o link da outra pergunta que parece ser igual antes de marcar como duplicata, pois talvez aquela pergunta não supri a dúvida que a pessoa tem.

Comment: Talvez não basta. o fato é que supre. E o fato não ter o termo não significa que a pergunta não é duplicada. Duplicação não significa ter os mesmos termos, significa apenas querer o mesmo resultado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eis uma solução simples:

```
var list = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4};
var rnd = new Random();

var query =
    from i in list
    let r = rnd.Next()
    orderby r
    select i;

var shuffled = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Foi o mais simples e que funcionou perfeitamente, só agora eu implantar numa função. Valeu aí, e aos demais, não sabia que era igual ao vetor do C

Comment: @LeonardoVIlarinho Mas não é igual. Tem alguns comportamentos semelhantes (usar como índice, por exemplo), mas as semelhanças acabam aí.

Comment: @LeonardoVIlarinho O melhor mesmo e' ler a [documentacao de `List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx). No fundo da pagina tem exemplos uteis.

Comment: Sim, não é igual kk é mais ou menos como Python né.. Não dá pra se comparar com C pois vetor armazena um item em dada posição, logo lista de string seria completamente diferente.. @dcastro valeu pelo link, vou dar uma olhada

Answer (score 1):

[Esta resposta ensina a fazer alguns algoritmos, como o de Fisher-Yates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1262619/1314276), mas é importante observar que esse algoritmo não é 100% aleatório, segundo a própria resposta. A resposta dá outras soluções mais confiáveis, mas para fins de simplicidade, vou manter apenas a primeira:

```
private static Random rnd = new Random();  

public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)  
{  
    int n = list.Count;  
    while (n > 1) {  
        n--;  
        int k = rnd.Next(n + 1);  
        T value = list[k];  
        list[k] = list[n];  
        list[n] = value;  
    }  
}
```

Uso:

```
List<int> numeros = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
numeros.Shuffle();
```

Para somar o primeiro com o terceiro elemento, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
var soma = numeros[0] + numeros[2]; // 0 é a primeira posição, 2 é a terceira.
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta [resposta já existe no site desde 21/05/2014](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17797/101). Na verdade esta pergunta é a [duplicata da duplicata](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86011/101). Como ela ficou aberta e foi respondida, vou responder também.

Note que não mudei a solução (aqui eu tirei a parte que melhorava o método para poder escolher qual faixa de dados deseja, mas não muda a execução em si), que é o importante. apenas tirei do exemplo a parte das *strings*. Se o problema é não saber somar elementos do *array*, então a pergunta deveria ser essa.

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class Sorteio {
    public static void Main() {
        int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        array.Shuffle();
        foreach (var valor in array) WriteLine(valor);
        WriteLine("Soma: {0}", array[0] + array[2]); // soma 1o. e 3o. elemento
        //vamos de novo
        array.Shuffle(); //com poucos númros tem chance de repetir
        WriteLine($"Soma novo sorteio: {array[0] + array[2]}"); // soma 1o. e 3o. elemento
    }
}

namespace System.Collections.Generic {
    public static class IListExt {
        static Random r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

        public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list, int lowerItem, int upperItem) {
            upperItem = upperItem > list.Count ? list.Count : upperItem;
            lowerItem = lowerItem < 0 ? 0 : lowerItem;
            for (int i = lowerItem; i < upperItem; i++) {
                int j = r.Next(i, upperItem);
                T tmp = list[j];
                list[j] = list[i];
                list[i] = tmp;
            }
        }

        public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list, int upperItem) => list.Shuffle(0, upperItem);

        public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list) => list.Shuffle(0, list.Count);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/6uzpYZ). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BaCXOK). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/Shuffle.cs).

Para atribuir para uma variável é só fazer isto:

```
var soma = array[0] + array[2]; //listas começam em zero então o elemento sempre é -1 ao desejado
```

Para mais detalhes, consulte as respostas já existentes lá na pergunta original.