# Lista aleatória gerada incorretamente

Tags: c#, .net, lista, random

Quero gerar uma lista de carros com características aleatórias de marca, modelo, cor e ano. Esses valores são armazenados em uma lista carro. O problema é que, na hora de fazer o *loop* que chama a função `gerarCarro()`, que adiciona valores aleatórios à lista carro, os valores, a partir do terceiro carro começam a ser todos iguais.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class MainClass
{
  public static List<string> marcaLista = new List<string>();
  public static List<string> modeloLista = new List<string>();
  public static List<string> corLista = new List<string>();

  public static List<string> carro = new List<string> ();

  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    marcaLista.Add("Toyota");
    marcaLista.Add("BMW");
    marcaLista.Add("Volkswagen");
    marcaLista.Add("GM");
    marcaLista.Add("Mercedes");

    modeloLista.Add("1.0");
    modeloLista.Add("1.4");
    modeloLista.Add("1.6");
    modeloLista.Add("1.8");
    modeloLista.Add("2.0");

    corLista.Add("Branco");
    corLista.Add("Prata");
    corLista.Add("Preto");
    corLista.Add("Cinza");
    corLista.Add("Vermelho");

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
      gerarCarro ();
      foreach (string item in carro)
      {
        Console.WriteLine (item);
      }
      Console.WriteLine ();

      carro.Clear ();
    }

  }

  public static void gerarCarro ()
  {
    int randomizer;

    Random random = new Random ();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
      randomizer = random.Next (0, 5);

      switch (i)
      {
        case 0:
          carro.Add (marcaLista[randomizer]);
          break;
        case 1:
          carro.Add (modeloLista[randomizer]);
          break;
        case 2:
          carro.Add (corLista[randomizer]);
          break;
        case 3:
          carro.Add (random.Next (2000, 2018).ToString());
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: pf Cria uma class pro carro rs

Comment: Esse código é muito confuso, ele poderia ser feito de uma forma muito mais simples. Eu tive até dificuldade de entender o real problema, tenho a impressão que a solução está errada porque o problema está mal definido.

Comment: O problema está na instanciação do `Random` dentro do método `gerarCarro()`. Ignorando o resto do código. Como é instanciado com o construtor sem parâmetros apanha o mesmo `seed` para as várias instanciações, logo gera os mesmos pseudo aleatórios

Comment: Ainda sou iniciante em programação, por isso o código é confuso hahaha. O que sugerem para fazê-lo funcionar corretamente? Não entendi como corrigi-lo de fato.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu sei que não é exatamente do jeito que queria, mas assim aprende fazer do jeito certo. O principal problema é que estava gerando uma nova semente randômica toda vez que chama o método, e ela acaba sendo a mesma. Semente deve ser gerada apenas uma vez na aplicação, e tornando ela membro da classe faz com que isto ocorra.

Também organizei e modernizei o código. Ficou muito mais enxuto. Tirei o que não precisava. Troquei o *array* por uma classe que é assim que se faz em C#. Eliminei o laço (`for`) e o fluxo de seleção (`switch`) que gerava elementos porque ele só complicava o código sem gerar benefício. Fiz o carro ser retornado para não precisar de um membro da classe a toa.

Ainda dá para melhorar bem mais, mas assim aprende o certo sem ter que aprender coisas demais.

Faça códigos simples. Fica mais legível, mas fácil de dar manutenção, mais fácil de entender. Acostume-se usar o [padrão de nomenclatura do C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/101).

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MainClass {
    public static Random Random = new Random();

    public static List<string> Marcas= new List<string>() { "Toyota", "BMW", "Volkswagen", "GM", "Mercedes" };
    public static List<string> Modelos = new List<string>() { "1.0", "1.4", "1.6", "1.8", "2.0" };
    public static List<string> Cores = new List<string>() { "Branco", "Prata", "Preto", "Cinza", "Vermelho" };

    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            var carro = gerarCarro();
            WriteLine(carro.Marca);
            WriteLine(carro.Modelo);
            WriteLine(carro.Cor);
            WriteLine(carro.Ano);
            WriteLine();
        }
    }
    public static Carro gerarCarro() {
        return new Carro() {
            Marca = Marcas[Random.Next(0, 5)],
            Modelo = Modelos[Random.Next(0, 5)],
            Cor = Cores[Random.Next(0, 5)],
            Ano = Random.Next(2000, 2018) };
    }
    public class Carro {
        public string Marca { get; set; }
        public string Modelo { get; set; }
        public string Cor { get; set; }
        public int Ano { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/VIbEND). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pmSqgA). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/RandomCar.cs).

Se desejar evitar repetição da mesma característica não deve usar número randômicos e sim um [algoritmo Fisher-Yates](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17783/101).

Comment: faz diferença colocar o `seed` como `DateTime.Now.Millisecond`  ?

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Consegui entender perfeitamente o que você fez. Só um detalhe: pra quê serve aquele `static` no `using System.Console`? Rodei o código com o `static` e deu erro, mas sem o `static` roda certinho.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis não, isso é gambi que funciona em certas circunstâncias. A não ser que dê uma distância muito grande acaba gerando a mesma semente. Em teoria funcionaria se o relógio tivesse resolução extrema.

Comment: @Leo_gp que versão do C# está usando? Aquilo é para não ter que escrever o `Console` em todo uso dele.

Comment: Estou usando um compilador online mesmo. É o site repl.it. Creio que seja 4.0.4.0

Comment: @bigown blz, só uma curiosidade que já vi o pessoal comentando no forum msdn, obrigado =]

Comment: @Leo_gp que tragédia, essa sintaxe é errada, eles estão usando um compilador fora do padrão, eu evitaria usar isso.

Comment: @bigown o que você recomenda?

Comment: @Leo_gp divirta-se: https://www.visualstudio.com/pt-br/vs/community/

Comment: @Leo_gp na resposta tem o que eu usei. Também uso o http://ideone.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, fiz um código bem mais simples, para te ajudar com esse problema. Ainda acho que da para melhorar mais, principalmente usando o `LINQ`, mas como eu não sei usa-lo, fiz da minha maneira:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CarroSO
{
    class Program
    {
        static List<Carro> carros = new List<Carro>(); //Crio varios array para utilizar melhor os valores
        static string[] marcas = { "Toyota", "BMW", "Volskwagen", "GM", "Mercedes" };
        static string[] modelos = { "1.0", "1.4", "1.6", "1.8", "2.0" };
        static string[] cores = { "Branco", "Prata", "Preto", "Cinza", "Vermelho" };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int valor;
            Random r = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                do
                {
                    valor = r.Next(0, 5);
                } while (testarExistencia(modelos[valor])); //Checa se já existe o carro
                carros.Add(new Carro(marcas[valor], modelos[valor], cores[valor])); //Adiciona o carro, caso não exista
            }

            foreach (Carro car in carros) //Passa por todos os carros
                Console.WriteLine($"Marca: {car.marca} - Modelo: {car.modelo} - Cor: {car.cor}"); //Escreve cada um no console
        }

        static bool testarExistencia(string modelo) //Retorna true se já existe e false caso não exista
        {
            foreach (Carro carro in carros)
            {
                if (carro.modelo == modelo)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    class Carro
    {
        public string marca { get; set; }
        public string modelo { get; set; }
        public string cor { get; set; }

        public Carro(string marca, string modelo, string cor) //Constructor para criar um objeto do carro
        {
            this.marca = marca;
            this.modelo = modelo;
            this.cor = cor;
        }
    }
}
```

Perceba que eu o comentei para poder explicar um pouco de como ele funciona.