# Hashes podem ser diferentes para aos mesmos bytes?

Tags: c#, .net, criptografia, hash

Encontrei uma falha ou não estou sabendo lidar com *hashes*. Tenho duas *bytes arrays* aleatórias, uma gerada por um algoritmo e outra original. Estou tentando fazer o algoritmo ficar EXATAMENTE igual à original. Visualmente consegui, com os mesmos bytes, o mesmo tamanho nas mesmas posições.

Mas ao verificar os *hashes* usando SHA-256, dá diferença entre os *hashes* para as *byte arrays* idênticas.

[image: resultado]

> **`A`** é o **hash** da byte-array original
>
> **`A¹`** é o **hash** da byte-array gerada
>
> **`Ax`** são os bytes contidos na byte-array original
>
> **`Ay`** são os bytes contidos na byte-array gerada pelo algoritmo

Observem que, `Ax` e `Ay` são praticamente idênticas. Mas seus *hashes* são diferentes. O que está acontecendo?

Método usado para calcular os *hashes*:

```
public static string ToHex(byte[] bytes, bool upperCase) {

    using (var k = new HMACSHA256()) {
        bytes = k.ComputeHash(bytes);
    }

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(bytes.Length * 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        result.Append(bytes[i].ToString(upperCase ? "X2" : "x2"));

    return result.ToString();
}
```

Atualmente estou usando o .NET Standard 2.0.

Comment: **Obs:** Isso também acontece com outros hashes como o MD5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [documentação do construtor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256.-ctor?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Security_Cryptography_HMACSHA256__ctor) que usou diz que a chave secreta necessária para calcular o *hash* é gerada aleatoriamente. E em cada execução um novo objeto é criado. Então em execuções diferentes o resultado será diferente. É [o mesmo problema que as pessoas cometem com `Random`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/226458/101), só que o oposto, elas geram sempre a mesma semente, neste caso está sempre gerando uma diferente porque o objeto muda.

Se quer sempre o mesmo resultado deve fazer todos os cálculos com o mesmo objeto (o que pode não ser possível em alguns cenários, incluindo execuções diferentes) ou usar um [construtor com uma chave fixa](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256.-ctor?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Security_Cryptography_HMACSHA256__ctor_System_Byte___).

Nunca use uma classe sem ler toda documentação dela. Em alguns casos é bom ler até sobre outros tipos do *namespace* todo.

Comment: Não sabia que hashs tinham uma chave aleatória. Essa é nova.

Comment: @CypherPotato este tipo tem sim, afinal ela exige que sempre tenha uma chave para gerá-la, se você não fornece uma, a classe gera uma para você de forma aleatória.

Answer (score 5):

O que ocorre é porque está usando HMAC. O [HMAC é um MAC](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/kmd5.pdf), não uma HASH em si, ela também é chamada de "Keyed Hash". Alguns algoritmos de hashes recentes, como Blake2, possui o recurso de Keyed Hash dentro dela (podendo ser usada tanto pra MAC quanto para um KDF).

Todo MAC precisa de uma chave, sem ela não não há como garantir integridade e confidencialidade. Como dito pelo @Maniero a função usada gera uma chave para o HMAC, se ela não for defina.

Você pode usar diretamente o SHA256, a função de hash em si, com o [SHA256](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256.sha256(v=vs.110).aspx)