# Como gerar número de 5 dígitos automaticamente?

Tags: c#

Como posso gerar um número aleatório com 5 dígitos que não se repetem no intervalo de [10000 - 99999].

Montei a solução baixo e mandei gerar em um loop as vezes que executei não retornou números repetidos, mas não sei se é a melhor forma para fazer isso.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int GetNumeroConta()
        {
            Random a = new Random(DateTime.Now.Ticks.GetHashCode());
            Thread.Sleep(1);
            return a.Next(10000, 99999);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numero = GetNumeroConta();
            Console.WriteLine(numero);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Acho suplicata: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17783/101, na verdade tem várias: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+fisher

Comment: @bigown, tem como converter a lista de nomo para um número como eu descrevi na pergunta ? eu montei uma lista apenas para verificar se estava gerando um número repetido.

Comment: @Bacco, estou querendo um número e não uma lista de nomes.

Comment: Possível duplicata de: [Sorteio onde o nome não pode ser sorteado mais de uma vez](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17783/101)

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza a lógica é a mesma (mesmo no caso de nomes, você embaralha os "numeros" de cada um). Simplesmente você vai gerando um array ou lista de numeros do tamanho desejado, e vai "embaralhando" ele para aleatorizar. As posições mudam, mas só vai ter um de cada. Tem como otimizar o algoritmo de várias maneiras depois (pra não gastar muita memória à toa se for extrair poucos números, por exemplo), o fundamental é a lógica. Se quiser, pode [edit] a pergunta dando parâmetros mais detalhados, aí talvez possamos dar sugestões mais específicas para o seu caso.

Comment: Lembrando que, se ao editar a pergunta ficar realmente diferente das perguntas indicadas nos links acima, a sua pode ser reaberta pela comunidade sem problemas.

Comment: @Bacco, vou ver se consigo implementa aqui, aparentemente vai dar certo se der fecho a pergunta depois.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza de qq forma, se tiver dificuldade ou novas idéias, deixe comentário que eu ou outros colegas podemos tentar ajudar (seja na sugestão de solução, seja na edição da pergunta).

Comment: A solução aceita é altamente ineficiente e tem potencial, raro, de nunca encerrar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implemente um "cache" dos números aleatórios, assim, os números criados ficam armazenados em cache, e você verifica se ele existe ou não:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
...

static List<int> random_caches = new List<int>();

private static int GetNumeroConta()
{
    // não é necessário colocar o milissegundo para a semente
    // a semente gerada é com base em Environment.TickCount
    Random a = new Random();
    // para quê isso? é realmente inútil sendo que só irá atrasar em 1ms a semente
    //Thread.Sleep(1);

    // obtemos nosso número aleatório
    int c = a.Next(10000, 99999);
    // verifica se o número está em cache
    while(random_caches.Contains(c)) c = a.Next(10000, 99999);
    // adiciona o número ao cache
    random_caches.Add(c);
    // retorna
    return c;
}
```

---

Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OuMyfQ).